# ipadPro12.9 inch status bar text color in dark Gray in iOS 10?

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, ios10

I have uploaded testflight build from xcode 6.3.1, and my deployment target 7.0 and support iPad device landscape only.
When I install my build in iPad pro 12.9 inch (iOS 10), the status bar text in dark Gray.
I have attached screenshot, please help to fix this issue.
I got this issue in my application only, Other apps are working fine
[image: Status bar text issue].
Thanks in advance

Comment: Start by upgrading to Xcode 8. Why are you still using Xcode 6?

Comment: Good Question , To support lower version of the device.

Comment: What device do you mean? You can support iOS 7 with Xcode 8.